# Sobolev inequality with a constant independent of the support of the function

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am revising our PDE module and I came across the following version of the Sobolev inequality:
$$
\exists C>0 \forall u\in W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb{R}^n):\, \|u\|_{L^{p*}}\le \|Du\|_{L^p}\, ,
$$
where $p*$ is the usual coefficient. Now what stunned be that this constant shall not depend on the support of $u$. In Evan's book I found only proofs for bounded domains, for which I can totally agree, or for continuously differentiable $u$'s. But in general, couldn't I take $u$ to be constant to one on the set $[-M,M]$ and then going linearily down with slope one and remaining zero after hitting zero? In that case $M$ to infinity would produce a contradiction, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This is only true for the critical exponent $p^*=np/(n-p)$ and $p<n$. The one-dimensional counterexample you sketched doesn't really apply. (Although, for $n=1$ it's okay to use $p=1$ and $p^*=\infty$; then the statement is true with $C=1/2$.)

At the critical exponent, both sides of the inequality scale the same way: replacing $u$ with $u(\lambda x)$ yields the same power of $\lambda$ on both sides. Hence, whatever constant works for the unit ball also works for *all* bounded domains, hence for all compactly supported functions. And then it works for $W^{1,p}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by the density of compactly supported functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But what if I would rotate my example around the y-axis, it would then be two dimensional. I am not doing scaling, I know that scaling doesnt work. The area would be bounded by $M^2$ but the derivative would still be constant, right?

Comment: The perimeter grows with $M$, too.